# How to add text to video by time use ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I create my slideshow with command:

```
"ffmpeg" -f concat -safe 0 -i /path/to/text.txt -i /path/to/audio.mp3 -vsync vfr -pix_fmt yuv420p /path/to/output.mp4
```

The contents of text.txt

```
file '/path/to/img1.jpg'
duration 6
file '/path/to/img2.jpg'
duration 6
file '/path/to/img3.jpg'
duration 6
file '/path/to/img4.jpg'
duration 6
file '/path/to/img5.jpg'
duration 6
file '/path/to/img6.jpg'
duration 6
```

The video has been cretaed perfectly. Now I want to add titles for each images displayed. Example:

- img1.jpg displayed, show title `Title 1`
- img2.jpg displayed, show title `Title 2`
- img3.jpg displayed, show title `Title 3`

I search a lot but got any solutions. Anyone help me. I'm stuck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to add daisychained drawtext filters.

```
-vf "drawtext=text='Title1':enable='between(t,0,6)',
     drawtext=text='Title2':enable='between(t,6,12)',
     drawtext=text='Title3':enable='between(t,12,18)'"
```

Consult the docs for [drawtext](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1) to see all options. You'll want to specify fontfile, fontcolor, fontsize and x,y.

Comment: I tried to demo, its look good. But texts are overlapped. Have you any ideas?

Comment: Overlapped throughout or temporarily?

Comment: full duration of video. Next line of text overlaps previous line

Comment: So Title3 overlaps with Title1?

Comment: yap bro. All line texts overlap together :(

Comment: You may have to make video CFR by adding `fps=25` before first drawtext. --or-- change time expression to `enable='eq(n,0)'` ..etc